# Adding index slows query

Tags: mysql, indexing

I am trying to optimize a query

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT booking.id)
FROM ride 
       LEFT JOIN spot s1_ ON ride.from_spot_id = s1_.id
       LEFT JOIN spot s2_ ON ride.to_spot_id = s2_.id
       LEFT JOIN booking ON ride.booking_id = booking.id
       LEFT JOIN contact ON booking.contact_id = contact.id
WHERE (contact.first_name LIKE UPPER('%GAE%') OR contact.last_name LIKE UPPER('%GAE%') OR contact.email LIKE UPPER('%GAE%'))
  AND booking.paid_at IS NOT NULL
  AND booking.cancelled_at IS NULL;
```

The query was executing in 2s or so. I added an index on booking.cancelled_at

```
alter table booking add index booking_cancelled_at (cancelled_at);
```

And now it takes around 15s!

I went looking and found I might want to add a composite index on cancelled_at and paid_at. I tried that but MYSQL was still choosing the cancelled_at index. I then try to delete the cancelled_at index to force the composite one. I was still around 15s.

The conclusion is : without index 2s, with index (single or composite) 15s.

I looked at the plans :

With index
[image: With index]

Without index
[image: Without index]

I am not sure why a full scan is faster than using index ?

Any guidance or indication on how to solve this would be much appreciated!

Thanks,

Comment: Are you sure you have posted the EXPLAIN plans from the two different queries? They look identical.

Comment: I can't really see why these are OUTER JOINs !?! Or, in fact, why spot appears in the query at all !?

Comment: Also, are you sure that you're using a case sensitive collation?

Comment: What's table c4_???

Comment: If you don't need `LEFT`, don't use it.  It does not seem to be necessary here.

Comment: Leave out tables you don't need -- `ride` and `spot`.

Comment: Don't use `UPPER()` if you have a case_insensitive collation.

Answer (score 0):

For the given column you only need to check whether it's `null` or not, I do not see the point of indexing that. Instead, since `booking.paid_at` mustn't be `null`, I would modify the `join` with `booking` and `contact` to `inner join` and use the criteria which are in the where for `booking.paid` and `booking.cancelled_at` in the on criteria.

Example:

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT booking.id)
FROM ride 
       JOIN booking ON ride.booking_id = booking.id
       AND booking.paid_at IS NOT NULL
       AND booking.cancelled_at IS NULL
       JOIN contact ON ON booking.contact_id = contact.id
       AND (contact.first_name LIKE UPPER('%GAE%') OR contact.last_name LIKE UPPER('%GAE%') OR contact.email LIKE UPPER('%GAE%'))
       LEFT JOIN spot s1_ ON ride.from_spot_id = s1_.id
       LEFT JOIN spot s2_ ON ride.to_spot_id = s2_.id;
```

If it's still slow, you could preselect the `contact` ids before the query and use the in operator.